# Flutter: How do I avoid repetition of try-catch-exception?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the code I want to avoid repeating. If possible also try block.

```
try {
//
    } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
      log('Timeout Error: $e');
      rethrow;
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      log('Socket Error: $e');
      rethrow;
    } on Error catch (e) {
      log('General Error: $e');
      rethrow;
    } catch (e) {
      log('All other Errors: $e');
      rethrow;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function like:

```
void tryCatch(Function f) {
  try {
    f();
  } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
    log('Timeout Error: $e');
    rethrow;
  } on SocketException catch (e) {
    log('Socket Error: $e');
    rethrow;
  } on Error catch (e) {
    log('General Error: $e');
    rethrow;
  } catch (e) {
    log('All other Errors: $e');
    rethrow;
  }
}
```

and then anywhere you want to use it do

```
tryCatch((){
  //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One trivial answer could be to refactor that `try-catch` cascade in a dedicated function or class, in which you return the value if everything's all right, or handle the corresponding error.

I guess yours is just an example code, but if you're just interested in logging an error and then `rethrow`, you don't need to distinguish between those exceptions and errors.

You can easily retrieve your error's type like so:

```dart
try {
  // some risky code
} catch(error, stackTrace) {
  print(error.runtimeType);
  print(error);  // calls its internal toString() method
  rethrow;
}
```

Even the above example could be refactored in a dedicated function or class, by the way.

If you're looking into something even more specific let me know, because I'm kinda curious about this, too.